# Round a Date() to the nearest 5 minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript

Using a `Date()` instance, how might I round a time to the nearest five minutes?

For example: if it's 4:47 p.m. it'll set the time to 4:45 p.m.

Comment: Are you using `Date` instances or strings?

Comment: THanks for the quick response mates, yes i am using Date() instance.

Comment: There's no need to edit the question title to mark the question as "Solved", that can be indicated by selecting the right answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round time to the nearest quarter hour in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968250/how-to-round-time-to-the-nearest-quarter-hour-in-javascript)

Answer (score 268, accepted):

That's pretty simple if you already have a `Date` object:

```
var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;
var date = new Date();  //or use any other date
var rounded = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff)
```

Comment: @Jick If an answer works for you then you should click the green tick to mark it as an accepted answer. That way, both you and the answerer get a little boost to your reputation and you get a nice fuzzy feeling inside

Comment: In case you want to round it up all the time. Just use `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.round`. That way you can always round up by 10 minutes for instance.

Comment: You don't even need to use `getTime` as it will use `valueOf` implicitly, eg `new Date(Math.round(date / coeff) * coeff)`

Comment: TypeScript complains about left-hand arithmetic, so adding getTime() actually fixes that error. Not that I advocate for the usage of TS for normal applications, but I'm building a financial application so I am being extra careful.

Answer (score 23):

## Round to nearest x minutes

Here is a method that will round a date object to the nearest x minutes, or if you don't give it any date it will round the current time.

```
function getRoundedDate(minutes, d=new Date()) {

  let ms = 1000 * 60 * minutes; // convert minutes to ms
  let roundedDate = new Date(Math.round(d.getTime() / ms) * ms);

  return roundedDate
}


// USAGE //

// Round existing date to 5 minutes
getRoundedDate(5, new Date()); // 2018-01-26T00:45:00.000Z

// Get current time rounded to 30 minutes
getRoundedDate(30); // 2018-01-26T00:30:00.000Z
```

Comment: Note: this is working on the UTC time. It does not matter for truncating to the nearest five minutes but won't work if truncating to the hour in local time since some time-zones are not full hours.

Answer (score 20):

With ES6 and partial functions it can be elegant. Choose if need to round to closest or always down/up:

```js
const roundTo = roundTo => x => Math.round(x / roundTo) * roundTo;    
const roundDownTo = roundTo => x => Math.floor(x / roundTo) * roundTo;
const roundUpTo = roundTo => x => Math.ceil(x / roundTo) * roundTo;

const roundTo5Minutes = roundTo(1000 * 60 * 5);
const roundDownTo5Minutes = roundDownTo(1000 * 60 * 5);
const roundUpTo5Minutes = roundUpTo(1000 * 60 * 5);

const now = new Date();
const msRound = roundTo5Minutes(now)
const msDown = roundDownTo5Minutes(now)
const msUp = roundUpTo5Minutes(now)

console.log(now);
console.log(new Date(msRound));
console.log(new Date(msDown));
console.log(new Date(msUp));
```

Comment: Great answer! I wanted to round down to nearest 15 mins, and this did the job

Comment: Simplifying `const date = new Date(); const interval = 1000 * 60 * intervalMins; return new Date(Math.ceil(+date / interval) * interval);`

Answer (score 6):

I know it is bit late for answer but maybe it can help someone. If you take the minutes by the following

```
new Date().getMinutes()
```

you can take the last 5 minutes by

```
new Date().getMinutes() - (new Date().getMinutes()%5)
```

Comment: simple & easy for me

Answer (score 5):

[Date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) now has a function which will round minutes on dates. See https://date-fns.org/v2.21.3/docs/roundToNearestMinutes

```js
const roundToNearestMinutes = require('date-fns/roundToNearestMinutes')
// OR: import roundToNearestMinutes from 'date-fns/roundToNearestMinutes'
console.log(roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), {nearestTo: 5}));
// e.g. 2021-05-19T22:45:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably less efficient but here's another alternative:

```
debug('Current timestamp:', timestamp);

timestamp.setMilliseconds(0);
timestamp.setSeconds(0);
timestamp.setMinutes(Math.round(timestamp.getMinutes() / 5) * 5);

debug('Rounded timestamp:', timestamp);
```

> ```
> Current timestamp: 2019-10-22T09:47:17.989Z
> Rounded timestamp: 2019-10-22T09:45:00.000Z
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to get the next 5 minute cycle using pure JS

```js
function calculateNextCycle(interval) {
    const timeStampCurrentOrOldDate = Date.now();
    const timeStampStartOfDay = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    const timeDiff = timeStampCurrentOrOldDate - timeStampStartOfDay;
    const mod = Math.ceil(timeDiff / interval);
    return new Date(timeStampStartOfDay + (mod * interval));
}

console.log(calculateNextCycle(5 * 60 * 1000)); // pass in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

recently found a very efficient way to round off the date to a timeframe

in short:

```
// minutes
var tf = 15; // 5,10,13,15, 60, - what ever you want
var dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
var minues = dt.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes; // use TotalMinutes, TotalSecibds, TotalMillisecons  and etc
var roundedMinutes = (minues - (minues%tf));
var roundedDate = dt.Date.AddMinutes(a);
```

I bit of my testing in LINQPad

```
// minutes
var tf = 15; // 5,10,13,15, 60, - what ever you want
var dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
var minues = dt.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes;
dt.Dump();
minues.Dump();
(ms%tf).Dump();
var a = (minues - (minues%tf));
a.Dump();
dt.Date.AddMinutes(a).Dump();
```

output:

```
13.07.2018 7:43:58 - current date
463,981443103333 - total mins
13,9814431033333 - rest
450 - rounded minutes value
13.07.2018 7:30:00 - rounded date
```

Comment: This looks like C# to me, the question is about JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@qc/date-round) `@qc/date-round` that can be used. Given that you have a `Date` instance to be rounded

```
import { round } from '@qc/date-round'

const dateIn = ...; // The date to be rounded
const interval = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 minutes
const dateOut = round(dateIn, interval)
```

Then you can use [`date-fns`](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) to format the date

```
import format from 'date-fns/format';

console.log(format(dateOut, 'HH:mm')) // 24-hr
console.log(format(dateOut, 'hh:mm a')) // 12-hr
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution (round up or down):

```
const fixedTime = (isRoundUp ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(time / 60_000 / minutesRange)) * 60_000 * minutesRange;

// minutesRange: number -> 1, 5, 15, 30, etc // minutes
// isRoundUp: boolean
// time: number // millis
```