# Round up the time to next quarter hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

For Example

```
The time is 8:05 -> it will round up into 8:15
The time is 8:27 -> it will round up into 8:30
```

The Time is always round up to the next quarter hour not this example below.

```
The time is 8:05 -> it will round up into 8:00
The time is 8:23 -> it will round up into 8:30
```

Is there any trick how to achieve this method? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @azad Thanks for the comment but that link is not what i needed, my question is it round up to the next quarter hour. The link you given is round the time only.

Comment: @P.James can you explain (preferably with examples) what exactly you want and how the linked post doesn't help? Also show what you have tried and explain how it isn't working

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10789415/283366) and swap `5` to `15` and `Math.round` for `Math.ceil` (to round up)

Comment: then what is the rounded value for `:16`

Comment: @phil The linked post given it's ony get the nearest quarter minute. In my question here is the time must be round up to the next quarter hour time. example: `code` My Time is 2:05 -> the result is 2:15 || My Time is 2:07 -> the result is 2:15`code`.

Comment: @phil ok, i will try it. thanks

Comment: @azad It will round up into `:30`