# Round datetime to the last 10 minutes JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, time, rounding

For my application is need the current datetime. But I need to round that to the nearest 10 min. I accomplished this with Math.round. The problem is that I need it to round to the LAST 10 min. Not up to the next. Because I won't have that data yet.

For example:

16:33 = 16:30 || 16:38 = 16:30  || 16:41 = 16:40

How can I do this?

```
const coeff = 1000 * 60 * 10;
const date = new Date();  //or use any other date
let roundDate = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question, your code is working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789384/round-a-date-to-the-nearest-5-minutes-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Math.floor but divide the value by 10, then multiply by 10.

Example:

```js
var x = 11;
console.log(Math.floor(x / 10) * 10);
```

Date Example:

```js
let date = new Date();
console.log(date);

let min = date.getMinutes();
date.setMinutes(Math.floor(min / 10) * 10);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed :) I will mark it as the answer

Comment: No worrries @Trisha

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.floor()`:

```js
const coeff = 1000 * 60 * 10;
const date = new Date("2019-01-03T13:18:05.641Z");

let floorDate = new Date(Math.floor(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);

console.log(date);
console.log(floorDate);
```