# How can I round time to hours and minutes instead of hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript, function, date, datetime, time

My function returns the time like this `10:43:22` for example. How can I round the time to the closest minute so `10:43:22` becomes `10:43` and `10:43:44` becomes `10:44`.

```
function time (){
    let date = new Date()
    let time = date.toLocaleTimeString("it-IT");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round a Date() to the nearest 5 minutes in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789384/round-a-date-to-the-nearest-5-minutes-in-javascript) it's for 5 minutes but you can easily change that

Comment: you use a datetime formatter. Also, remember to ask yourself whether what you want makes sense. Just "not showing seconds" is almost _always_ fine because when it comes to time, it's not "10:44" until it's been more than "10:43:59". Time does not generally "round up".

Answer (score 2):

I would get the milliseconds of that date and then round that value to minutes (1 minute = 60,000 milliseconds).

```js
function createRoundedDate(date) {
  var ts = date.getTime();
  ts = Math.round(ts / 60000) * 60000;
  return new Date(ts);
}

console.log(createRoundedDate(new Date()))
```

Comment: Adding `.toLocaleTimeString("it-IT",{hour:'numeric',minute:'2-digit'})` would finish the job. :-)

Answer (score 0):

we can use the below code to create the new Date by removing the seconds part

```
var d = new Date()
var d1 = new Date(d.getYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate(),d.getHours(),d.getMinutes())
console.log(d1.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT'))
```

Comment: This only removes the seconds, but does never round up?

Comment: It does not round. The correct answer in in the link from the first comment

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, and handle going over hours etc. (60,000 ticks is 1 min)

```
function time(){
  let date = new Date()
  let dateMins = new Date(date.getYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDay(),date.getHours(),date.getMinutes())
  let roundedDate = new Date(dateMins.getTime() + date.getSeconds() > 30 ? 60000 : 0 )
  let time = roundedDate.toLocaleTimeString("it-IT");
}
```

Comment: By "ticks" you mean milliseconds yes?