# Using the Kendo DateTimePicker (MVVM) Rounding (Display Only)

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

Using the Kendo DateTimePicker (MVVM) How can I round time to the nearest minute.

For example the data holds the date/time as 12/07/2021 06:59:59 but I would like my HTML template to show this value rounded up to 12/07/2021 07:00 is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can round the the nearest minute by listening to the `change` event and setting the value to the rounded `Date`. There are various questions on Stack Overflow regarding rounding to the nearest minute. Here is one example I incorporated.

Simply change the seconds value and see the time update.

```js
const MINUTE_IN_MILLIS = 6e4;

// // https://stackoverflow.com/a/10789415/1762224
const roundToNearest = (date, coefficient) =>
  new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / coefficient) * coefficient);

const roundToNearestMinute = (date) => roundToNearest(date, MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

$('#date-time-picker').kendoDateTimePicker({
  format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt',
  value: new Date(),
  dateInput: true,
  change: function() {
    this.value(roundToNearestMinute(this.value()));
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: top;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js
"></script>
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <input id="date-time-picker" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this example will change the value of the control I would like to keep the value just display a rounded version, so is there some type of formatting which can do this?