# Convert Time Stamp to half hour

Tags: vb.net

Im writing a function to convert the time to the nearest half hour using Visual Studio 2010. 
Eg, 15:23 to 15:30 then if 15:05, it will convert to 15:00.

Anyone has ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What datatype are you currently holding the timestamp in?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method:

```
Public Enum eRoundingDirection
    up
    down
    nearest
End Enum

Public Shared Function RoundDateTime(dt As DateTime, minutes As Integer, direction As eRoundingDirection) As DateTime
    Dim t As TimeSpan
    Select Case direction
        Case eRoundingDirection.up
            t = (dt.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue)).Add(New TimeSpan(0, minutes, 0))
        Case eRoundingDirection.down
            t = (dt.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue))
        Case Else
            t = (dt.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue)).Add(New TimeSpan(0, minutes \ 2, 0))
    End Select

    Return DateTime.MinValue.Add(New TimeSpan(0, (CInt(t.TotalMinutes) \ minutes) * minutes, 0))
End Function
```

to round the current time to the nearest half-hour:

```
Dim rounded = RoundDateTime(Date.Now, 30, eRoundingDirection.nearest):
```

originally found(in C#) [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24582/Rounding-a-DateTime-object-to-a-defined-number-of)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer [how to round time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968250/how-to-round-time-to-the-nearest-quarter-hour-in-javascript)
It's a javascript example but the same should be possible with vb.net.