# Get times in 15 minute increments up to a specific time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js and would like to create an array that contains all of the times in 15 minute intervals from the current time.  So for example:

Current time is 1:35pm.  The next time would be 1:45pm, then 2:00, 2:15, 2:30, 2:45, etc. up until a certain point.

I'm really not sure how to this.  Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
function calculate(endTime) {
    var timeStops = [];
    var startTime = moment().add('m', 15 - moment().minute() % 15);

    while(startTime <= endTime){
        timeStops.push(new moment(startTime));
        startTime.add('m', 15);
    }

    return timeStops;
}
```

usage:

```
calculate(moment().add('h', 1));
```

This will return time intervals of every quarter of hour (like you said) h:15, h:30, h:45, h+1:00...  It also contains seconds, so you might set seconds to 0, since I was not sure if you need them or not.

[You also can see working example on FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9u3QD/1/)

Comment: Note, since time of writing moment API has changed so that the unit of time is specified after the amount.

startTime.add(15, m);

Answer (score 1):

I'm not as familiar with `momentjs` but this is relatively easy to do in pure Javascript. To get the closest 15 minutes you can [use this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968250/how-to-round-time-to-the-nearest-quarter-hour-in-javascript). Then if you put that in a date variable you can just add 15 minutes as many times as you want! So the resulting Javascript is:

```
var d = new Date();
var result = "";
for (var idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
{
    var m = (((d.getMinutes() + 7.5)/15 | 0) * 15) % 60;
    var h = ((((d.getMinutes()/105) + .5) | 0) + d.getHours()) % 24;
    d = new Date(d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay(), h, m, 0, 0);

    if (idx > 0) result += ", ";
    result += ("0" + h).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).slice(-2);

    d = addMinutes(d, 15);
}
```

[**SEE THIS IN A FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NvmZ2/)

*Notes* - I just added 15 minutes 3 times arbitrarily. You could calculate the difference between the time you want and now if you need a different number of intervals. Also note that I don't know exactly what this would do if it is almost midnight, though that would be easy enough to test and code around.

Best of luck!