# Find the Nearest Quarter Hour with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need a way to round to the closest quarter hour.

Given time: 08:22 AM => Rounded to: 08:15 AM

Given time: 08:23 AM => Rounded to: 08:30 AM

I have this function to find the current time:

```
    $scope.clock = "loading clock..."; // initialise the time variable
    $scope.tickInterval = 1000 //ms

    var tick = function () {
        $scope.clock = Date.now() // get the current time
        $timeout(tick, $scope.tickInterval); // reset the timer
    }

    // Start the timer
    $timeout(tick, $scope.tickInterval);
```

I then need to round my clock to the nearest quarter hour.

Comment: Maybe have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968250/how-to-round-time-to-the-nearest-quarter-hour-in-javascript).

Comment: Yes I saw that one. I was just wondering if there was an angular way to do the same thing. Thanks John.

Comment: Nope - not really something that angular handles. Use a third party library if you need better time handling in JS. Try momentjs.com