# make function round up to nearest quarter hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i make the function round to nearest 15 minute, not rounding down?
if its 10:46 it would round to 11:00

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/31L9d08s/

code:

```
 var now = new Date();
    var Minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var quarterHours = Math.round(Minutes/15);
    if (quarterHours == 4)
    {
        now.setHours(now.getHours()+1);
    }
    var rounded = (quarterHours*15)%60;
    now.setMinutes(rounded);
    now.setSeconds(0);
    now.setMilliseconds(0);


    console.log(now.getTime());


    var currentdate = new Date(now.getTime()); 
    var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                    + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                    + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                    + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                    + currentdate.getSeconds();


    console.log(datetime);
```

Comment: This is *so much better* than the previous time you asked this question.

Comment: That said, I know you were pointed to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968250/how-to-round-time-to-the-nearest-quarter-hour-in-javascript) earlier. Surely your question just involves doing that and adding 15 minutes?

Comment: it involves that, but not rounding it down @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Hence the "and adding 15 minutes"

Comment: can we chat @T.J.Crowder ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

```
new Date(Math.ceil(new Date().getTime()/900000)*900000);
```

Explanation: `new Date().getTime()` returns the current time in the form of a unix timestamp (i.e. the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC), which we round up to the nearest multiple of 900000 (i.e. the number of milliseconds in a quarter-hour) with the help of `Math.ceil`.

**Edit**: If you want to apply this to intervals other than 15 minutes, you can do it like that (e.g. for 30 minutes):

```
var interval = 30 * 60 * 1000; // 30 minutes in milliseconds
new Date(Math.ceil(new Date().getTime()/interval)*interval);
```

Comment: you probably have to compensate for timezoneOffset.

Comment: @Thomas: Why would you need to do that? Are there any timezones that work in something that's not a multiple of 15 minutes? But it's a good point if you're rounding to something that doesn't fit evenly into, say, a half-hour.

Comment: I think @Thomas is actually right. Theoretically, if there is a timezone whose offset from UTC is not a multiple of 15 minutes, the above would not work correctly.

Comment: could you edit it so i could do something like:

$int = 2;
then it would be the next 30 min.
$int = 3;
next 45 min, etc?

Comment: @TJCrowder, yea and nay. In this particular case you don't have to, I thought of a more generic implementation, where "15 Minutes" is just an argument.

Comment: @maria You can replace (both occurrences of) 900000 with anything you like, e.g. `(900000 * n)` where `n` is some variable.

Comment: i tried that @redneb but that would give me incorrect time.

Comment: @maria are you sure you tried it correctly? see my edit

Comment: would the $interval be if i multiply with two, i would get the next 15 minutes after the first 15 min? if not, how may i?

Comment: @maria I am not sure I understand your question, but if `interval` is 5 min then you get times like :00, :05, :10, :15, etc, or if it was 20 min you get times like :00, :20, :40, etc.

Comment: can we chat @redneb ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass any cycle you want in milliseconds to get next cycle example 2,4,8 hours

```js
function calculateNextCycle(interval) {
    const timeStampCurrentOrOldDate = Date.now();
    const timeStampStartOfDay = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    const timeDiff = timeStampCurrentOrOldDate - timeStampStartOfDay;
    const mod = Math.ceil(timeDiff / interval);
    return new Date(timeStampStartOfDay + (mod * interval));
}

console.log(calculateNextCycle(4 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 4 hours in milliseconds
```